# MySQL: `REFERENCES` vs `FOREIGN KEY` + `REFERENCES`

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

> MySQL: `REFERENCES` vs `FOREIGN KEY` + `REFERENCES`

I thought that `REFERENCES`was some sort of shorthand syntax for the more verbose `FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES` syntax.

However, the below table is not acting like it is constrained by a foreign key constraint. I can easily add a tuple with a `courseid` not in the `Courses` relation.

Can someone clarify this issue?

```
CREATE TABLE `Exam`(
    `courseid` VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES `Courses`(courseid) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    `examno` INT(1) DEFAULT 1 CHECK(`examno` >= 1),
    `weight` FLOAT(5) DEFAULT 1 CHECK(`weight` > 0),
    PRIMARY KEY(courseId, examNo)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of mysql are you using?

What do you get when you run this?

> show create table Exam;

What I get is:

```
     CREATE TABLE `Exam` (
     `courseid` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     `examno` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `weight` float DEFAULT '1',
      PRIMARY KEY (`courseid`,`examno`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

which means that MySQL is ignoring the "REFERENCES" portion of your create table statement.   I think that you do need the full statement like:

> FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
>           REFERENCES parent(id)
>           ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: Aha, what does the show command do? And how do I create multiple foreign keys in different tables?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-create-table.html  SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name     Shows the CREATE TABLE statement that creates the named table.

Comment: Re:  how do I create multiple foreign keys in different tables? --  Can you add the create statement for the courses table?  In order to create a foreign key between courses and exam tables, the key fields must be a primary key in both tables and they must be of the same type in each table.  Currently, exam.courseid is not a primary key in the exam table.